# autofilling a login box for an .exe program with shortcuts/scripts

Tags: windows, exe

I'm wondering if its possible to write a script or add a shortcut command or something to an .exe file that I open quite regularly and have to log on each time.

The program is called iMonitor which when you click on the .exe file opens up to a log in box with 3 fields, user name, password, and server.  Is there some standard format or way anyone knows of to auto-fill those fields or would it be a program specific thing they would have to write into the code itself to allow?

Thanks in advance

Chuck

Comment: There is no standard for autofill. It is a program-specific thing.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the reply raymond.